# Error on GEE: No features contain non-null values of "system:time_start"

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm calculating DVI over a region using MODIS. I am able to get the printout of the map properly but not the chart to retrieve the data. To calculate DVI, I did:

```
var dvi = img.expression(
    '(nir - red)',
    {
        red: img.select('sur_refl_b01'),    // 620-670nm, RED
        nir: img.select('sur_refl_b02'),    // 841-876nm, NIR
        blue: img.select('sur_refl_b03')    // 459-479nm, BLUE
      .rename('DVI')
    });
```

When I look at the inspector, I see the value for the DVI band, but the code for charting seems not to work. It says there's no system time.

```
var bandChart = ui.Chart.image.series(dvi, roi)
```

I also tried to add .filterDate ('2016-05-01', '2016-10-31') but it says the parameter is not a function. I.e.

```
var dvi = img.expression(
    '(nir - red)',
    {
        red: img.select('sur_refl_b01'),    // 620-670nm, RED
        nir: img.select('sur_refl_b02'),    // 841-876nm, NIR
        blue: img.select('sur_refl_b03')    // 459-479nm, BLUE
      .rename('DVI')
    });
```

I also tried to create a function (so as to specify timeframe) but that did not work either. How can I proceeed to get the chart?

```
var addDVI = function(image) {
  var dvi = img.expression(
    '(nir - red)',
    {
        red: img.select('sur_refl_b01'),    // 620-670nm, RED
        nir: img.select('sur_refl_b02'),    // 841-876nm, NIR
        blue: img.select('sur_refl_b03')    // 459-479nm, BLUE
      .rename('DVI')
      .filterDate('2016-05-01', '2016-10-31')

    });
    return image.addBands (dvi);
};
```

Comment: Please make your code reproducable by adding a link to your code. It seems like you will need a image collection instead of a single image to produce the chart.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like `img.expression(...).copyProperties(img, 'system:time_start')` (or use `image` if it's inside that function).  When you do a computation on an image, the derived image does not retain the properties of the original image.